# System always halt

Tags: touchpad, idle

Good day,
Thanks Bruno for the prompt response. First sorry for my bad writing. I'll try to clarify my problem.

Now my system already update to version 13.10.

The problem is my system always put on stop whenever there is no activity.

Example:

1. I open terminal then execute "sudo apt-get update" then I leave my laptop away, the update stop at 20%. After I move my mouse then the update continue.
2. When I watch a movie using vlc. Play the movie and change to full screen. After a while like 30-40 seconds the movie pause, and again after I move my mouse or hit any button on my keyboard the movie continue to play.
3. I downloading torrent file, a big file, I leave my laptop the whole night, the next morning the downloading just stop.

the problem my laptop cannot be on idle. means when I downloading a file or updating my system I just cannot leave my laptop away. I have to kept my laptop busy like surfing the internet...playing games etc.

Comment: What software do you use to watch the movie?

Comment: I'm using VLC. The same problem occur when I watch video from youtube. And when I use skype, the video just stop. after hit keyboard or move my mouse the video like normal. I just cannot sit and relax. Always put my hand and finger on the keyboard and mouse. Really sick and tired.

Comment: It appears to be an issue of you graphics card (drivers). Could you include information about your hardware in your question?